# Printed lines acting strange in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am tring to print out a load of lines in a few loops and I want to find a way of printing out the lines without using `\n` as that adds an empty line after each loop is completed. A sample of the code i have is as follows:

```
def compose_line6(self, pointers, pointers_synset_type):    
    self.line6 = ''
    for A, B in zip(pointers, pointers_synset_type):
        self.line6 += 'http://www.example.org/lexicon#'+A+' http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos '+B+'\n'
    return self.line6

def compose_line7(self, pointers, pointer_source_target):
    self.line7 = ''
    for A, B in zip(pointers, pointer_source_target):
        self.line7 += 'http://www.example.org/lexicon#'+A+' http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target '+B+'\n'
    return self.line7

def compose_contents(self, line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6, line7):
    self.contents = '''\
    '''+line1+'''
    '''+line2+'''
    '''+line3+'''
    '''+line4+'''
    '''+line5+'''
    '''+line6+'''
    '''+line7+''''''
    return self.contents

def print_lines(self, contents):
    print (contents)
```

When i print these this is what happens:

```
        http://www.example.org/lexicon#13796604 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos n
http://www.example.org/lexicon#00603894 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos a
http://www.example.org/lexicon#00753137 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos v
http://www.example.org/lexicon#01527311 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos v
http://www.example.org/lexicon#02361703 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos v

        http://www.example.org/lexicon#13796604 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target 0000
http://www.example.org/lexicon#00603894 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target 0401
http://www.example.org/lexicon#00753137 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target 0302
http://www.example.org/lexicon#01527311 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target 0203
http://www.example.org/lexicon#02361703 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target 0101
```

And i would like it like this:

```
http://www.example.org/lexicon#13796604 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos n
http://www.example.org/lexicon#00603894 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos a
http://www.example.org/lexicon#00753137 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos v
http://www.example.org/lexicon#01527311 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos v
http://www.example.org/lexicon#02361703 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos v    
http://www.example.org/lexicon#13796604 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target 0000
http://www.example.org/lexicon#00603894 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target 0401
http://www.example.org/lexicon#00753137 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target 0302
http://www.example.org/lexicon#01527311 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target 0203
http://www.example.org/lexicon#02361703 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target 0101
```

Help would be great thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close your quotes before you add newlines:

```
'''\
    '''+line1+'''
    '''+line2+'''
    '''+line3+'''
    '''+line4+'''
    '''+line5+'''
    '''+line6+'''
    '''+line7+''''''
```

You escaped the first newline, but it is still adding 4 spaces behind `line1`. Try this:

`print("\n".join([line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line 6, line7]))`

Comment: I am still getting the line breaks between each method? is there a way to solve this?

Comment: That's because you're adding newlines in your `compose_line` functions. Either use `"".join(...)` or (preferably) just remove the newlines that you are generating in your own functions.

Comment: could you possibly explain that a bit more? I have the `self.line7 = ''` removed but it is still leaving a space

Comment: You're doing this: `self.line7 += 'http://www.example.org/lexicon#'+A+' http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target '+B+'\n'` - you need to remove the `+'\n'` at the end of all those lines.

Comment: No i cant do that or it will just get printed as a big block of text, is there any other way about it? any other linebreak methods?

Comment: `"\n".join(...)` puts the newlines between every line for you.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
def compose_contents(self, line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6, line7):
    self.contents = '\n'.join([line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6, line7])
    return self.contents
```

and:

```
print contents,
```

Note the comma at the end!

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.x it will be `print "Text",` - nothing after comma.

In Python 3.x it will be `print("Text", end="")` - just special argument to `print()` function.

Comment: and if you `from __future__ import print_function`, then you can use the 3.x form in 2.x, in case version compatibility is important.